# Write a loop to pick up and merge overlapped part in a list

Tags: r, list, loops, sublist

I have a large list (`list_1920`) shown below.

```
city01 <- data.frame("city" = "01", "gender" = c("female", "male"), "number" = c(12,20))
city02 <- data.frame("city" = "02", "gender" = c("female", "male"), "number" = c(50,40))
list2019 <- list(city01, city02)
names(list2019) = c("city01_2019", "city02_2019")
city01 <- data.frame("city" = "01", "gender" = c("female", "male"), "number" = c(60,80))
city02 <- data.frame("city" = "02", "gender" = c("female", "male"), "number" = c(120,90))
list2020 <- list(city01, city02)
names(list2020) = c("city01_2020", "city02_2020")
list_1920 <- list(list2019, list2020)
list_1920
```

Thanks to the help from community member, I can now use `lapply` to pick up info for the same city in different years:

```
city01 <- lapply(list_1920, function(x) x$city01)
city02 <- lapply(list_1920, function(x) x$city02)

city01
#> [[1]]
#>   city gender number
#> 1   01 female     12
#> 2   01   male     20
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   city gender number
#> 1   01 female     60
#> 2   01   male     80

city02
#> [[1]]
#>   city gender number
#> 1   02 female     50
#> 2   02   male     40
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   city gender number
#> 1   02 female    120
#> 2   02   male     90
```

I am now trying to combine the two steps and achieve the same result in a loop, since I need to do one more step analysis based on the result above. I have tried:

```
picklist <- tibble("city" = c("01", "02")
plist <- unique(picklist$city) # plist returns "01" and "02"
for (i in levels(plist)) {
  lst[[i]] <- lapply(list_1920, function(x) x$[[i]] 
# I hope this will return the same result shown above
  new <- merge(lst[[i]][[1]], lst[[i]][[2]])}
# lst[[i]][[1]] is what returned in city01 in the result shown above
# lst[[i]][[2]] is what returned in city02 in the result shown above
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I received a message to debug `lst[[i]] <- lapply(list_1920, function(x) x$[[i]]`

It would be much appreciated if you could offer some help. Many thanks.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to pick out constant elements in the lists:

```r
city01 <- lapply(list_1920, function(x) x$city01)
city02 <- lapply(list_1920, function(x) x$city02)

city01
#> [[1]]
#>   city gender number
#> 1   01 female     12
#> 2   01   male     20
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   city gender number
#> 1   01 female     60
#> 2   01   male     80

city02
#> [[1]]
#>   city gender number
#> 1   02 female     50
#> 2   02   male     40
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   city gender number
#> 1   02 female    120
#> 2   02   male     90
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Allan, many thanks for your help! May I please ask a follow-up question? I have updated the question. What I've been trying is to combine these two steps (pick up city01 and city02 respectively) into a loop. However, this step doesn't work `lst[[i]] <- lapply(list_1920, function(x) x$[[i]] `. I doubt there might be something wrong with the brackets. It would be much appreciated it you could offer some insight on this. Many thanks indeed.